# Dynamic Delay Between Messages in Chatbot

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic, message-queue, messaging, chatbot

In the chatbot I’m developing I want the messages to be sent with a dynamic delay between messages. For instance the two messages “Hello” and “How are you?” should have a delay of 0.2 seconds between them. 
The delay is a function of how long the previous message was, so for instance: 
Number of Characters * 0.02 = Delay in Seconds

I’m struggling to come up with the tools and logic for how to build this without just putting threads on wait. This should scale even when the delay is several seconds and manage thousands of concurrent messages.

I’m sure this problem has been solved by many before me, but how? And what are the current best practices?

Comment: Is there a reason why [ActiveMQ delay delivery](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html) is not useful? I assume that you've come across this (it is the first result in Google when typing "activemq delay message")